# Getting a hyperlink to automatically break at punctuation marks

Tags: hyperref

In the example below, how can I get the hyperlink that prints as "doi:10.2307/1968102" to automatically break at any of the punctuation marks, i.e., the :, ., or /?

Note: I am compiling directly from the .tex file to the PDF, so the `breakurl` package will not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1}
N. Wiener, \emph{Tauberian theorems}, Ann. of Math. (2) \textbf{33} (1932),
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968102}{doi:10.2307/1968102}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Okay, it seems that if I apply `\nolinkurl` to the second argument of the `\href`, I get the behavior I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1}
N. Wiener, \emph{Tauberian theorems}, Ann. of Math. (2) \textbf{33} (1932),
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968102}{\nolinkurl{doi:10.2307/1968102}}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `breakurl` package solves your problem

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1}
N. Wiener, \emph{Tauberian theorems}, Ann. of Math. (2) \textbf{33} (1932),
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\rmfamily}
\burlalt{http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968102}{doi:10.2307/1968102}.
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968102}{doi:10.2307/1968102}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This works for `latex` then `dvipdf` commands.

**Edit:**
The strange thing is that compiling with `pdflatex` the same file do not produces the same output. You have to put this line

```
\burlalt{doi:10.2307/1968102}{http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968102}
```

to make it working.

Comment: I don't think the `breakurl` package works when compiling directly from the .tex file to the PDF? I added a note about that to my question. I basically want my hyperlink to break as if it was set up with `\burlalt`.

Comment: Do you mean that you compile your .tex file with LaTeX -> dvipdf to obtain your pdf file? In that case, I have updated my answer with your new requirements.

Comment: I mean that I'm compiling from the .tex file directly to the PDF using pdfLaTeX. I use TeXworks, if that matters.

Comment: If you try to compile the MWE I provide, does it works? (put that I add on my edit to make it working when you use `pdflatex`).